# could not access HTTP invoker remote service

Tags: spring, spring-remoting

Im using Spring and im trying to access a HTTP invoker remote service and have specified the url in the spring-http-client-config.xml.  But Im getting the below exception

```
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access HTTP invoker remote service at [http://blr1272d:8080/MaskOracle/remoting/securityService]; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Did not receive successful HTTP response: status code = 401, status message = [Unauthorized]
```

The configuration details that I have specified in the spring-http-client-config.xml are 
below

```
    <bean id="securityService"
      class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://blr1272d:8080/MaskOracle/remoting/securityService" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.him.mask.security.remote.service.SecurityService" />
    <property name="httpInvokerRequestExecutor" ref="httpInvokerRequestExecuter"/>

</bean>
 <bean id="httpInvokerRequestExecuter"  
 class="org.springframework.security.remoting.httpinvoker.AuthenticationSimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor" />
```

Im not sure why im getting this exception. Please help me in resolving the issue. Thanks

Comment: ... status code = 401, status message = [Unauthorized]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your service at `http://blr1272d:8080/MaskOracle/remoting/securityService` requires authentication but your `securityService` doesn't use any credentials.

Try to use `org.springframework.richclient.security.remoting.BasicAuthCommonsHttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean` and set `authenticationToken` property.